# Getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >=3 when trying to export JTable contents to a text file

Tags: java, jtable

I am currently trying to write a finance program for one of my projects at college in Java. One of the project requirements consists of exporting my JTable data to a text file. Here is my code (Assume that the table is already populated).

When trying to write to the file, however, I get this error:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 3

Any ideas of what I have done wrong...

I originally followed this guide: http://1bestcsharp.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/java-io-how-to-export-jtable-data-to-txt-File-In-Java.html

but used a different method for writing to the file (https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java.html)

Thanks,

Ben.

```
    try {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    System.out.println(tbl_Finance.getRowCount() + " " + tbl_Finance.getColumnCount());
    for(int i = 0; i < tbl_Finance.getRowCount(); i++) {
       for(int j = 0; i < tbl_Finance.getColumnCount(); j++) {
           bw.write(tbl_Finance.getValueAt(i, j) + " ");
        } 
      bw.write("\n_________\n");
    }
    bw.close();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Exported To " + fileName);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
for(int j = 0; i < tbl_Finance.getColumnCount(); j++)
```

to

```
for(int j = 0; j < tbl_Finance.getColumnCount(); j++)
```